# plus(+) sign in special character match expression of sed

Tags: regex, bash, unix, sed

If string contains multiple (+) signs and if it needs to be captured .. how it can be put inside [] ?

```
comp_arg=`echo $element | sed -nr 's/.*-c([a-zA-Z0-9_-+]*)<\/text>.*/\1/p'`;
```

The issue is that `+` inside `[]` isn't working and reporting errors as follows:

> sed: -e expression #1, char 38: Invalid range end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is not due to `+` inside `[...]`, it is due to unescaped `-` (or hyphen) not at first or last position inside. An unescaped `-` in the middle of character class makes it a range. In your case it is trying to establish a range between `-` and `+` which is invalid since `+` comes before `_` in ASCII table.

Try this instead:

```
sed -nr 's/.*-c([a-zA-Z0-9_+-]*)<\/text>.*/\1/p'
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem does not have to do with `+`, but with `-` placed within a quantifier expression. This is a special symbol in there and tries to match a range of elements, so `a-z` means "all letters from a to z". So saying `_-+` is trying to match all characters between `_` and `+`.

See how this works without the hyphen:

```
$ echo "hello+bye" | sed -r 's/[a-z+]*//'
               # return empty
```

But starts failing when we add the hyphen:

```
$ echo "hello+-bye" | sed -r 's/[a-z-+]*//'
sed: -e expression #1, char 12: Invalid range end
```

**The solution is to put it to the end of the expression**:

```
$ echo "hello+-bye" | sed -r 's/[a-z+-]*//'
               # return empty
```